# Having problems using numpy linalg svd

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, linear-algebra, svd

I'm testing svd decomposition with simple matrix

```
 A=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

but when I use :

```
U,D,V=np.linalg.svd(A)
```

the output are U whit shape (2,2), D with shape (2,) and V with shape (3,3)
the problem is the shape of V, the svd algorithm should return a 2x3 matrix since my original matrix is a 2x3 matrix and i'm geting 2 singular values, but it return a 3x3 matrix, when i take V[:2,:] and make the product:

```
U.dot(np.diag(D).dot(V[:2,:]))
```

it returns the original matrix A, what is happening here?
thank you for your reading and answers and sorry for the grammar, i'm beginning in english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the [docstring](https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html), but it might take a few readings to get it.  The boolean parameter `full_matrices` determines the shape of the returned arrays.  In your case, you want `full_matrices=False`, e.g.:

```
In [42]: A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

In [43]: U, D, V = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices=False)

In [44]: U @ np.diag(D) @ V
Out[44]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
```